# Referencing a control as an incremented variable

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table, code-behind

I'm trying to fill a table with an indeterminate number of images.  I know the number will never be more than 6.

What I've done is this:

## asp.net

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img id="igImage1" src="Image1" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img id="igImage2" src="Image2" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img id="igImage3" src="Image3" alt=""/></td>    
        <td><img id="igImage4" src="Image4" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img id="igImage5" src="Image5" alt=""/></td>
        <td><img id="igImage6" src="Image6" alt=""/></td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

## c# code-behind

```
public void ReadPhotoInfo()
{
    // Get the current logged in user's ID
    using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strCon1))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT uFileName, PhotoInfo FROM tmpUserPhotos WHERE UserName = '" + CurrUser + "'", con2))
    {
        con2.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader DT2 = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int X = 1;
            while (DT2.Read())
            {
                igImage[X].src = DT2["uFileName"].ToString();
                igImage[X].alt = DT2["PhotoInfo"].ToString();
                X = X + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This clearly doesn't work, but the idea is to loop through DT2 and read the filename and photoinfo fields into each of the appropriate td's.

The error I'm getting is: **Error   92  The name 'igImage' does not exist in the current context**

Can someone help me do this?

Comment: Just use a `Repeater`.

Comment: Can you do that if you want columns and not rows?

Comment: You can repeat anything; the template can be whatever you wan, so yes.  A `DataGrid` would be something that requires you to have a table and have each item in the datasource map to a row in that table.  It's mostly just a special case of a `Repeater`.

Answer (score -1):

If you add the `runat="server"` attribute to your `img` tags, then statements such as `igImage[X].Src = "~/img/pic.jpg";` will work fine in the code behind.

Comment: Still doesn't like it.  :(